# effect of relational inverse operator upon a relation A, B, C

Tags: relations

Can someone clarify this for me please:

If I have a relation `R`  which is of the form `A \mapsto (B \mapsto C)` and I use the relational inverse operator on `R` do I get:
`(C \mapsto B) \mapsto A)` or is it `(B \mapsto c) \mapsto A`?

Thanks.

Comment: So, you have a relation relating elements of your first set, $A$, with the second set, $(B\to C)$... that is the second set is a set containing relations from $B$ to $C$... The inverse relation would map your second set (*unchanged*) to the first set... just like it would if it were $X\to Y$ the inverse relation would be going from $Y$ to $X$... here we just have rather than $Y$ we have $(B\to C)$.

Comment: Thanks. That's really helpful.